# How to align these label/input box/botton on IE7

Tags: html, css

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/y4yJX/) you can find a Fiddle example, and here is the code :

```
<div class="menu-alto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a title="Link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>

        <li class="newsletter">
            <a title="Newsletter" href="#">Newsletter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <label style="color:#99cc00">cerca&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" style="width:116px;" />
            <input type="submit" style="width:40px;" class="bottone" value="VAI" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.menu-alto ul
{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}

.menu-alto li
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    font-size:10px;
    padding-right:16px;
}

.menu-alto li a:link,
.menu-alto li a:visited
{
    color:#7c7c7c;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

.menu-alto li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.menu-alto .last
{
    padding-left:5px;
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
}

.menu-alto .bottone
{
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    height:21px;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

As you can see (just on IE7) the label with the text *CERCA* is not align (as middle) with the other links, and on Chrome (for example) the button is in the botton of the vertical-middle align. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should vertically center using `vertical-align:middle;` on all your `<li>` children instead of using relative position.